# Accessing Microsoft Graph from C# Web API

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, adal

I have a following application architecture:

- Angular 5 client
- C# Web API protected by Azure tokens

The client and the API are registered in Azure app registrations and the client correctly authenticates against the API endpoints with the token. So I am getting the data which I need. So far, so good.

But then, I would like to make the API layer (server-side) to fetch some data from Microsoft Graph (e.g. a simple "Me" request, https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/) . I was trying to use the token which the client sends to the API, and to create a token using the app secret. Both approaches gives me an insufficient privileges error from the MS Graph side.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the App Registration to have rights to access Microsoft Graph. You can do so by going to the application registration, and...

- Click Settings
- Go to Required permissions
- Click Add
- Click Select an API
- Select Microsoft Graph and click Select
- Under Application Permissions, check the correct permissions

Click Select to select the permissions, then Done to finish adding API access.

**IMPORTANT!**
Click the Grant permissions button to actually grant the permissions to the application. An admin has to grant these permissions, you can do so by clicking the button. Any changes you make in the permissions you enable for the application require you to explicitly grant the permissions by clicking the button.

More information, about for instance Application Permissions vs Delegated Permissions, can be found in this article: [HowTo: invite AAD user with Microsoft Graph](https://www.rickvandenbosch.net/blog/invite-aad-user-microsoft-graph/)

Comment: There are also two approaches that can be taken here: Application permissions (requires admin approval always) or Delegated permissions + On-behalf-of (requires admin approval sometimes). On-behalf-of allows you to exchange the token the API received for a new delegated token, and then call an API as the app + user. App permissions give organization-wide access but are more reliable and simple. Delegated permissions give tighter access but are more fragile :)